# unsaturated fatty acids and hydrogenation

Tags: molecular-biology, lipids, fatty-acid-synthase

what is the need to hydrogenate unsaturated fats?

When we hydrogenate the unsaturated fatty acid, we eliminate double bonds by adding hydrogen atoms, and this straightens out the natural bent shape of the unsaturated fatty acids. But why would we choose to hydrogenate unsaturated fatty acids before consuming them?

Comment: It makes them (more) solid.